# Unity 2D particle collision not getting event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, particle-system, unity3d-2dtools

When I turn on particle system in my 2D game, and check the collision button in Inspector window, I expect to get an event `On-Particle-Collision`, but it never happens!

I even added an extra thing named `WorldParticleCollider`, but also, no collisions.

I have tried even adding this `WorldParticleCollider` to the enemy(just for no reason), and sure it did not work.

Screenshot:

> [image: Screenshot:]

Why is this ?

Comment: What collider are you using?

Comment: @firebellys Unity3d 2d game, what do you mean?

Comment: what are you colliding the particle with? particles only work with 3d colliders at the comment. So if you turn on collisions, they won't trigger or interact unless they hit another 3d collider like a box or capsule.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [question at the Unity forums](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/2d-physics-particle-systems-collision.210556/) `OnParticleCollision` may not support 2D games just now.

> according to Unity Roadmap, this feature will be available with Unity 5.3 (Dec 8, 2015).

Maybe you can use a 3D collider for your 2D game.

Remember the collider cannot be a trigger!

Comment: 4 years later still the same problem. I can see my objects going through the particles in 2D space and its not firing up the event.